# VBA Spreadsheet which uses 5 drop down boxes in a spreasheet to Pick one of 10 shippers

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet where users manipulate 5 drop down menus to pick which of 10 shipping options they should use.

I'm using VBA to write the function for the result. For the second and third drop downs I need it to check against two lists of about 6 states each. If both states turn up on the same list I want it to pick *shipperA* or *shipperB* depending on which list they turn up on. What's the easiest way to do this? Thank you!

**Code Below:**

```
Function shipperPicker(o, oS, dS, w, p, d) As String

If w = "Under 150" Then
    shipperPicker = "FedEx Ground" 
ElseIf o = "Store" And d = "Under 75 Miles" Then
    shipperPicker = "Matrix"
ElseIf w = "Under 150" And p = "Samples" Then
    shipperPicker = "Fedex Ground, $10 per 3 samples"
ElseIf w = "Under 150" And p = "Molding" Then
    shipperPicker = "FedEx Ground, $20"
ElseIf w = "Over 8 000" Then
    shipperPicker = "Chasity in transportation"
ElseIf p = "Laminate, Vinyl, 5/8 inch Bamboo" Then
    shipperPicker = "FedEx Freight"
ElseIf oS = "foo" Then
    shipperPicker = "foo 2"
ElseIf dS = "foo" Then
    shipperPicker = "foo 3"
ElseIf d = "foo" Then
    shipperPicker = "foo 4"        
Else
    shipperPicker = "Call store for prefered shipper and Quote"  
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Function shipperPicker(o, oS, dS, w, p, d) As String

    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range

    Set rngA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("states").Range("A1:A6")
    Set rngB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("states").Range("B1:B6")

    If w = "Under 150" Then
        shipperPicker = "FedEx Ground"
    ElseIf o = "Store" And d = "Under 75 Miles" Then
        shipperPicker = "Matrix"
    ElseIf w = "Under 150" And p = "Samples" Then
        shipperPicker = "Fedex Ground, $10 per 3 samples"
    ElseIf w = "Under 150" And p = "Molding" Then
        shipperPicker = "FedEx Ground, $20"
    ElseIf w = "Over 8 000" Then
        shipperPicker = "Chasity in transportation"
    ElseIf p = "Laminate, Vinyl, 5/8 inch Bamboo" Then
        shipperPicker = "FedEx Freight"

    ElseIf Not rngA.Find(oS, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing And _
        Not rngA.Find(dS, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

        shipperPicker = "ShipperA"

    ElseIf Not rngB.Find(oS, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing And _
        Not rngB.Find(dS, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

        shipperPicker = "ShipperB"

    ElseIf d = "foo" Then
        shipperPicker = "foo 4"
    Else
        shipperPicker = "Call store for prefered shipper and Quote"
    End If

End Function
```